# Scroll GridView with header

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a gridview in my app with some info above. I'd like the "header" to scroll with the grid (inside a unique scroll bar) in order to gain space in the screen.

iFunny implements that, you can check the screenshots below.I have tried but a grid view does not support headers or footers. How can I do it?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at this one https://github.com/munix/GridViewHeader

Comment: and this it he Google implementation of it, feel free to grab the code and use it: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java